# Read a record selected in DataGridView table and read through info of that record into fields that is not shown in the table

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, .net-3.5

*Note: Some of the code included below has already been used in some of my other questions but regarding other issues. I have also edited most of the post to cause less confusion!*

I originally included the MessageBox.Show() to see if the records looped and displayed into the fields correctly but have since removed it. For instance, if I open a file the MessageBox.Show() will appear with the first record displayed, select the OK button again and the second record is displayed and so on. Instead of this, I want each row to act as the MessageBox.Show() and correctly present the relevant row - i.e. Record Number is 4 and record 4 shows. I can read the amount of X records in the file and I know how to create X amount of records in the DataGridView table.
What **should** happen:

- User opens file
- Summary of data is populated in DataGridView table
- Each row that is selected displays data in more detail in fields.

I have a DataGridView SelectionChanged method below which just gets the row number I have selected. I thought about passing the number into my ReadWeldRecs Method:

```
private void Dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rec_num_to_read = Dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
    ReadWeldRecs(rec_num_to_read);
}
```

Currently, even if I just attempt to FileStream.Seek a position in my opened file with the row value from above, it crashes. So, I removed the while loop and data comes back blank (doesn't read at all).

```
private void ReadWeldRecs(int row_to_read)
{
    byte[] Rec = new byte[1024];
    int length = Rec.Length;

    using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(import.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using(BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(Fs))
    {
        while ((length = Br.Read(Rec, 0, 1024)) > 0) // IF I REMOVE THIS IT DOESN'T CRASH BUT IT DOESN'T READ ANY DATA AND COMES BACK BLANK
        {
            Fs.Seek(row_to_read * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin); 

            // Rest of code to read file information...
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT

I can now activate the method to read data from the file when a row is selected, however the data is wrong - some but few right :/

```
private void Dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] Rec = new byte[1024];
    long length = file_info.Length;
    int rec_num_to_read = Dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1;

    using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(import.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(Fs))
    {
        while ((length = Br.Read(Rec, 0, 1024)) > 0)
        {
            foreach (var rec in Rec)
            {
                Fs.Seek(rec_num_to_read * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Position file to record

                Label_Product1.Text = DecodeString(Rec, 3, 12);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is really off about your code. I'm not sure I understand your goal but two points that you should be aware of:
1. You call `ReadWeldRecs(sum);` with `sum` but then you overwrite `RecordNumber ` with `RecordNumber = 0;`.
2. The `while` loop condition is `while (Rec.Length > 0)` but you don't change `Rec` size, so it's equivalent to `while (1024 > 0)` which is `while(true) {}`. You should set `while(Rec_Len > 0)` and remove the `break` statement. Start from here, maybe it will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: That makes sense and I can see why it didn't work correctly. I have followed what you said and applied it to my application, now it has read and displayed a record (also removed the MessageBox) with the correct amount of rows :) Just need to work my head around initiating the records to each DataGridView row. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the while loop you provided and it crashes my app :/ I don't understand why it does that.

Comment: You can move the `Read` line to the loop: `while ((Rec_Len = Br.Read(Rec, 0, 1024)) > 0)`, make sure that `Rec_Len` is initialized properly with value greater than 0, so it can first enter the loop.
And speaking of crash, what kind of crash? What exception thrown?

Comment: Right, I will try that. "ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected" with the description: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x1b72dba0 to COM context 0x1b72ddf0 for 60 seconds... (really long). I've researched this exception just briefly now and a repeating suggestion is to use BackgroundWorker. Will look into the exception and ways to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code does work but is very slow :/ so I'm currently trying to work around it to improve the speed.

```
byte[] Rec = new byte[1024];
FileInfo file_info = new FileInfo(import.FileName);
long a = file_info.Length;
int rec_num_to_read = Dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1;

using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(import.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(Fs))
{
    while ((a = Br.Read(Rec, 0, 1024)) > 0)
    {
        Fs.Seek(rec_num_to_read * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin); // I moved this out of the foreach loop

        foreach (var rec in Rec)
        {
            Label_Product1.Text = DecodeString(Rec, 3, 12);
            // Some more info to decode
        }
    }
}
```